# Hide every null variable from collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Sometimes `{{$vs->users2}}` or `{{$vs->users3}}` will have null value, i need to hide them if both or one of them have null value. i tried with isset or isnull but none of them work.

```
@foreach ($vs as $vs)
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-hide="$vs->users == null">
            <h4>{{$vs->gps_vs}}</h4>
            <h5>Participantes: {{$vs->users4}} {{$vs->users3}} <a>VS</a> {{$vs->users1}} {{$vs->users2}}
            </h5>
            <a>Empieza: {{$vs->time_vs}} {{$vs->date_vs}} </a><a>Creado por: {{$vs->users4}}</a> 
        <div class="right2">
                {!! Form::open(['action' => ['MatchController@destroy', $vs->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                {{Form::submit('Borrar evento', ['class'=>"btn btn-danger"])}}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>       
    </div>    
@endforeach
```

my form where the null value comes

```
<select class="col-sm-2 form-control" name="users3">
        <option selected value=null>Nothing</option>
      @foreach($users3 as $users3)
        @if ($users3->id == 0 or $users3->id == Auth::user()->id);
        @else
        <option value="{{$users3->nick}}">{{$users3->nick}}</option> 

        @endif
      @endforeach

    </select>
```

Comment: Can't see using isset or isnull in your code .

Comment: Can you share what's the output when you do "dd($vs->users2) or dd($vs->users3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
{{$vs->users2 or ''}}
```

If it is throwing error you can disable it by `@` [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
{{@$vs->users2}}
```

You can use the same for `users3` also.

**EDIT**

Change ur foreach to `@foreach ($vs as $v)`.

> **Note: You just can't have array and value name same while looping.**

and replace every vs with v inside that.

**EDIT 2**

Your final html should look like this

```
@foreach ($vs as $v)
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-hide="$v->users == null">
            <h4>{{$v->gps_vs}}</h4>
            <h5>Participantes: {{$v->users4 or ''}} {{$v->users3 or ''}} <a>VS</a> {{$v->users1 or ''}} {{$v->users2 or ''}}
            </h5>
            <a>Empieza: {{$v->time_vs}} {{$v->date_vs}} </a><a>Creado por: {{$v->users4}}</a> 
        <div class="right2">
                {!! Form::open(['action' => ['MatchController@destroy', $v->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                {{Form::submit('Borrar evento', ['class'=>"btn btn-danger"])}}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>       
    </div>    
@endforeach
```

Comment: When i try {{$vs->users2 or ''}} i dont now why it shows "1", if i try {{@$vs->users2}} nothing happens

Comment: what's in it `$vs->users2`? if `$vs->users2` contain value it will show else it won't show anything, it will suppress undefined error

Comment: there is a string value, its from a form where you can select a name or nothing which is set on null

Comment: done but it keeps the same, i uploaded the form if there is something wrong

Comment: It keeps the same means? That data is still not coming? or some other issue?

Comment: I think i did a mistake i puted value=null but is value=" "

Answer (score 1):

As @quickSwap said {{@$vs->users2}} or {{$vs->users2 or ''}} it works but i forgot to put in the migrations

```
$table->string('users3')->nullable();
```

to enable null values in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to @quickSwap's answer `or` blade function is removed in Laravel 5.7 in favor of PHP's built in `??` null coalesce operator. You can use

```
{{$vs->users2 ?? ''}}
```